# varchar to datetime in mysql compare

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a data like 'ddmmyyyy' like this format in my datebase and it datatype is also varchar(8) now i need to compare the date using between query

my table data is

```
 | id    |  enquiry_date   |    dept_name |
 |----------------------------------------|
 |  1    | 02112004        |      LAB     |  
 |  2    | 31122005        |    RESEARCH  |
 |  3    | 26052005        |      LAB     |  
 |  4    | 16042006        |    RESEARCH  |
```

Now i need to take records from 05-02-2005 to 12-11-2006 like that. here its varchar how to compare it please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your table, use date data type instead!

Comment: If you really want to stay at the varchar type have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Actually i received the data from web services there they will inserted in this format i need take fetch the records here

Comment: @FerhatSayan But i seperate the string in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
STR_TO_DATE(enquiry_date,'%d%m%Y')
```

So you can compare like

```
where date_format(STR_TO_DATE(enquiry_date,'%d%m%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') > '05-02-2005'
and date_format(STR_TO_DATE(enquiry_date,'%d%m%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') < '12-11-2006'
```

Comment: No Boss here i got only null values only it doesnt worked out

Comment: @NandhiniKarnan:- Updated my answer. Please check